# Angular directive watch doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, watch

I have object in controller

```
$scope._id = '12345';
$scope.messages = {
    '12345': [
        {
        author: 'Vasya',
        message: 'Message from Vasya'
        },
        {
            author: 'Bob',
            message: 'Message from Bob'
        }]
};
```

Html tag:

```
<div message-list="{{_id}}")></div>
```

My directive:

```
var App = angular.module('app', [])
.directive("messageList", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {          
            scope.$watch('messages[attrs.messageList]', function(newVal,oldVal) {
                if (newVal!==oldVal)
                {
                    console.log("newVal",newVal);
                    console.log("oldVal",oldVal);
                }
            },true);
        }
    }
});
```

But watch doesn't work when i push new element into array $scope.messages['12345'].

Comment: if i'm right the scope that you are trying to watch is the "directive scope" and is not related with the controller scope where object "messages" is.
try to watch it directly in the controller or use the rootscope.

$rootScope.$watch($rootScope.messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [plunkr.](https://plnkr.co/edit/wa7KcVoi6oMvZQctNqf2?p=preview) Open the console while viewing the plunker to see changes.

You would need a `$watch` on the `messages` object:

```
scope.$watch('messages', function(newVal,oldVal) {
    if (newVal!==oldVal)
    {
        console.log("newVal",newVal);
        console.log("oldVal",oldVal);
    }
},true);
```